# Does Tibco EMS support Network of Brokers?

Tags: activemq-classic, tibco-ems

Does Tibco EMS supports "Network of Brokers" topology similar to ActiveMQ?
Or any other similar feature to support distributed queues and topics for scalable design?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, TibcoEMS supports distributed queues and topics.